# How to find a newly joined node has windows, Linux or Solaris operating system?

Tags: linux, windows, solaris

I am doing a network service topology diagram. I need to identify the newly added computer's operating system so that I could run different scripts based on OS. How could I identify the newly added computer's operating system?

Comment: How much access do you have to these newly-joined nodes?  Are they built to certain standards?  The more information you provide, the better answers you're going to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nmap does it: [Nmap os detection](https://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html)

```
nmap -O
```

> -O (Enable OS detection)
>
> Enables OS detection, as discussed above. Alternatively, you can use -A to enable OS detection along with other things.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you OS info for NIX:

```
cat /etc/*rel*
```